# Optional and non-optional not able to be returned from function that returns an optional

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I'm working on writing a function that returns what the next node of a tree would be from any node, if doing an in-order traversal. The function has an optional return, which is needed if there is no next node (i.e. we're at the last node). I return both an optional and non-optional from the function and at both places there are compiler errors. Here is the code:

```
class TreeNode<T> 
{
    var leftChild : TreeNode?
    var rightChild : TreeNode?
    var parent : TreeNode?
    var value : T

    init(withValue:T) {
        self.value = withValue
    }

    func nextInOrderNode<T>() -> TreeNode<T>?
    {
        if var nextNode = rightChild
        {
            while nextNode.leftChild != nil {
                nextNode = nextNode.leftChild!
            }
            return nextNode //error 1
        }
        else
        {
            var nextNode = parent
            var currentNode = self
            while nextNode?.rightChild !== currentNode {
                currentNode = nextNode!
                nextNode = nextNode?.parent
            }
            return nextNode //error 2
        }
    }
}
```

The errors are:

```
error 1: Cannot convert return expression of type 'TreeNode<T>' to return type 'TreeNode<T>?'
error 2: Cannot convert return expression of type 'TreeNode<T>?' to return type 'TreeNode<T>?'
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here because from what I've seen, it seems like this should work. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is unrelated to optional vs non-optional return values.
In

```
func nextInOrderNode<T>() -> TreeNode<T>?
```

you introduce a *new* placeholder type `T`, locally to this method,
which is unrelated to (and hides) the placeholder type `T`
in `class TreeNode<T>`.

The solution is simple:
just remove the placeholder in the method declaration:

```
func nextInOrderNode() -> TreeNode<T>?
```

You don't need it here because the scope of `T` in `class TreeNode<T>`
is the entire class definition, including all methods.

Comment: That's it. I started off with the function as a global function then changed it to a member function. Thanks for your help.